# How to access clipboard data for automation?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, clipboard

I am using selenium webdriver and ruby. Long story short i am working on a web application which on click of a button copies all the data in the text field to the clipboard. I want to access that data and compare if a string is present.

I have installed clipboard and win32/clipboard gems.Here is my code

```
include Win32 
abc = Clipboard.data
em  = " ooyalaPlayer = OO.Player.create('playerContainer',"
puts 'true' if abc.include? em
```

Here is the error stack

```
$ jruby tests/embed_add_remove_playlist.rb -b firefox -a staging
ui-test-support will place screenshots and additional logs under:
results_dir=E:/testing/behavioral_tests/themebuilder/results
c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36: Use RbConfig inste
ad of obsolete and deprecated Config.
LoadError: no such file to load -- win32-clipboard
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at E:/testing/behavioral_tests/themebuilder/lib/embed_helper.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at tests/embed_add_remove_playlist.rb:8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install 'win32-clipboard':

```
gem install win32/clipboard
```

Then do following :

```
require 'win32-clipboard'
include Win32 

abc = Clipboard.data
puts abc
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a linux or osx system, you can do the following:

Write text to a file like this:

```
IO.write('/tmp/msg.txt', 'hi')
```

Read it back like this:

```
IO.read('/tmp/msg.txt')
```

Frequently, I want to read a file into my clipboard ***

```
Clipboard.copy IO.read('/tmp/msg.txt')
```

And other times, I want to write what's in my clipboard to a file ***

```
IO.write('/tmp/msg.txt', Clipboard.paste)
```

*** Assumes you have the clipboard gem installed

See: https://rubygems.org/gems/clipboard